# WildFly + MariaDBについて

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, wildfly

動作環境 : Windows7 32bit, Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen, Java8, MariaDB10.3, WildFly12

・初めてWildFlyを使います。そこでいくつか質問させてください。

①WildFlyはTomcatを含んでいるとのことですが、既にEclipseにTomcatサーバーを立てていた場合、これらは競合したりして良くなかったりすることはありますか？実際にTomcatで動かそうと思ったらWildFlyが動き出したりその逆だったりと、慣れるまで少しややこしいです。

②ググっていると、module.xmlの書き方、standalone.xmlの書き方にかなり違いがあるのですが、最もシンプルなデータベース接続方法(データソースの用意？)はどういった手法がありますか？サーブレットのようにlib内にjarを配置というのは意味がない、むしろ必要なくなりますか？

③単純にサーブレット&JSPで作ったプロジェクトをWildFlyで動かしてみたいのですが、プログラム側でTomcat使用時とは変えなきゃいけない書き方、注意事項等はありますか？

※いずれ仕事でWildFlyを使わなければいけなくなるため、ひとまず独自の機能的なことは置いておいて、Tomcat代わりに使うところから…というレベルです。特にDB接続がかなり勝手が違うようなので、xmlの書き方や、このxmlはいらないとかあればご教授頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1):

> ①WildFlyはTomcatを含んでいるとのことですが、既にEclipseにTomcatサーバーを立てていた場合、これらは競合したりして良くなかったりすることはありますか？実際にTomcatで動かそうと思ったらWildFlyが動き出したりその逆だったりと、慣れるまで少しややこしいです。

デフォルトのポート番号はWildFly、Tomcatとも8080なので、両者を同じサーバー上で起動すればポートの競合は発生します。その場合、後で起動した方がエラーになるので、どちらか一方だけを起動するか、ポート番号の設定を変えればいいです。「Tomcatで動かそうと思ったらWildFlyが動き出したりその逆だったり」というようなことはありません。Eclipseで開発し、Tomcat上で動作確認したWebアプリケーションをwarファイル形式でエクスポートして、WildFlyにデプロイすればいいだけです。それから、WildFlyはTomcatを含んでいるのではなく、Tomcatのソースコードをベースに開発されたという方が正しいです。

> ②ググっていると、module.xmlの書き方、standalone.xmlの書き方にかなり違いがあるのですが、最もシンプルなデータベース接続方法(データソースの用意？)はどういった手法がありますか？サーブレットのようにlib内にjarを配置というのは意味がない、むしろ必要なくなりますか？

[初心者向けのWildFlyの記事](https://qiita.com/tama1/items/829be5aacd81637ae73a)があるので、これを読んでみて下さい。DBアクセスの設定手順についても書かれています。

> ③単純にサーブレット&JSPで作ったプロジェクトをWildFlyで動かしてみたいのですが、プログラム側でTomcat使用時とは変えなきゃいけない書き方、注意事項等はありますか？

基本的にはありません。TomcatもWildFlyもJava EEという標準仕様を実装したソフトウェアであるため、基本的にはうまく動作するはずです。Tomcatはサーブレットコンテナと言われるソフトウェアで、Java EEという標準仕様のうちコアな仕様（サーブレット/JSPなど）しか実装していません。これに対してWildFlyはJava EE準拠の参照実装であり、すべての仕様を実装しています。したがって、Tomcat上で動作するようなWebアプリケーションであれば、WildFlyでも動作します。とはいっても、完全に互換性があるというわけではないので、実装によっては修正が必要な場合もあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！MariaDBだといまいち扱いづらかったのですが、MySQLに替えてサイトを参考させて頂いたらいっきに解決しました！助かりました！