# コマンドプロントでCould not locateと表示される

Tags: コマンドプロンプト, wildfly

コマンドプロントで以下のコマンドを入力し

C:\jboss\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\docs\contrib\scripts\service\service install /config standalone.xml /desc "WildFly 10.1.0.Final" /logpath e:\logs\jboss /startup

Could not locate "C:\jboss-modules.jar"

と表示されます。
どのようにすれば実行できるでしょうか。

Comment: 文言の感じからすると、C:ドライブのルートに"jboss-modules.jar"をコピーしようとしてUACとか保護の問題でエラーになっていそうです。何か環境変数の設定が不足しているとかでは？ JavaのランタイムかSDKがインストールされていないとか。なおServiceとしてではなくスタンドアロンのインストール手順がこの記事のようです。[WildFly 10.1 installation on Windows](http://www.learn-it-with-examples.com/middleware/wildfly/installation/install-wildfly-101-on-windows.html) 他にStackOverflowではこんな記事も。[WildFly + MariaDBについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52039/26370)

Comment: 環境変数の設定はパスのことでしょうか。パスの設定はwork＞release＞2017MMDDにしたいです。

Comment: 何か専用の名前の環境変数とかありそうですが。何か事前準備も含めた正しいインストール手順の説明などがあれば、インストール場所も合わせてきちんとその通りに作業してみると良いでしょう。